# ¿Error en mi código?

Tags: c

Disculpen pero estoy en clases y apenas estoy aprendiendo c he hice este programa, el objetivos es que ingresaras un numero mínimo y máximo y imprimirá los números que hay entre esos 2 y adelante imprimirá su potencia pero no los imprime me podrían indicar donde esta el error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int leermax() {

    int M;
    printf("ingrese el numero maximo: ");

    scanf("%d",&M);
    return M;

}

int leermin(){

    int m;
    printf("ingrese el numero minimo: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    return m;

}


int potencia (int p){

    return (int) (pow (p,2));

}

void tabla (int M,int m){

    for(int n=m;n<=M ;n++){
        printf("%d %d \n", n, potencia(n));
    }

}
int main(){

    int x,y;
    x=leermin();
    y=leermax();
    tabla (x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas confundiendo cual es menor y mayor

por esa razon jamas entra al for, porque en tu caso  `M` es mayor a `m`, y tu `for` dice que `M` tiene que ser mayor a `m`

```
for(int n=m;n<=M ;n++){
        printf("%d %d \n", n, potencia(n));
    }
```

prueba con

```
x=leermax();
y=leermin();
```

o en un mejor caso para probar, prueba con datos estaticos, de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int potencia (int p){

    return (int) (pow (p,2));

}

void tabla (int M,int m){

    for(int n=m;n<=M ;n++){
        printf("%d %d \n", n, potencia(n));
    }

}
int main(){

    int x,y;
    x=8;
    y=6;
    tabla (x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Nota: hice la prueba con esos datos e imprime lo siguiete:

> 6 36
>
> 7 49
>
> 8 64

Comment: cierto muchas gracias